Recovering Files from HDDs After LVM Destruction and Inodes deleted
TL;DR
I have a media server with 3 x 4TB HDDs. My cousin created an LVM across the disks while I was away, but after a few days, it started having issues, and he destroyed the LVM without proper data migration. Now, one HDD has lost its inodes, and I can't find the files. I have a 1TB external HDD for small transfers. Any ideas on how to recover the lost files, especially some important family videos?
FULL STORY
I have this media server with 3 hard disks of 4TB each. Having purchased these HDDs incrementally, I never set up a RAID on them (also because one is slightly different from the others, and I didn't want to take the risk). A few months ago, I lost physical access to the server due to work and university commitments, and when I returned a few days ago, I discovered that my distant cousin had made a mess. During my absence, this guy learned about the media server and decided to create an LVM across the 3 disks. Initially, it seems he wanted to set up a RAID, but after discovering that one of them was different, he searched online and found LVM. The point is that after a few days, the LVM started having issues, and in his wisdom, he destroyed the LVM without the proper data migration procedure to preserve the data (this was because, according to him, the files should have been saved on the individual HDDs, so even if he unmounted the LVM, Linux would still find them). The moral of the story is that he could no longer find the files (obviously), and he even tried to recover them with TestDisk or similar tools (he only remembers that at one point there were inode errors, and he thought it would be a good idea to repair the filesystem). So my situation is this: I have two 4TB HDDs, with one (the one that was supposed to contain the index) no longer having the inodes pointing to the actual files. Currently, I only have one external 1TB HDD on which I can possibly make small transfers. Does anyone have any ideas on how to recover the files? (I’m not interested in all of them, but there are some family videos that I would like to recover).
Thank you very much, and have a great day.

I doubt it but this will be your best bet: https://www.ufsexplorer.com/  It supports LVM.  But the best results are made when nothing is done to the system after the 1st failed actions. Anything else tends to nuke recovery. Not sure if that is the case if it is only inodes; UFS explorer will tell you. "especially some important family videos?". But important means you have a backup and that would mean you can just erase the whole system, reinstall and restore that backup.

@Rinzwind Yes, from that point of view, I am prepared. They are old videos that are available on VHS or CD/DVD, so I have the backup. The only thing was whether I could do the recovery to save myself the 'effort' of having to clean and fix them again. Thanks, I'll try

Excellent admin behaviour!! :)  Now you only need to clubber your cousin
